# How to change title bar font in win apps by C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, titlebar

how i change title bar font of form in windows application by C# ?

i found this code but not working and doesn't drawing titlebar:
how can i do this?
thanks all

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
{
    base.WndProc(ref msg);
    const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x85;

    if (msg.Msg == WM_NCPAINT)
    {
        this.Text = "";// remove the original title text

        IntPtr hdc = GetWindowDC(msg.HWnd);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(hdc);
        Font ft = new Font("Arial", 16);

        g.DrawString("Hello World title", ft, Brushes.Red, new PointF(20.0f, 0.0f));

        ReleaseDC(msg.HWnd, hdc);
    }
}

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Vista and Windows 7 you will need to disable Aero for the code to work.

Take a look at the answer I provided to the following question
[How to add an extra button to the window's title bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841180/how-to-add-an-extra-button-to-the-windows-title-bar/2841197#2841197)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible since you can only edit the text but not the markup.

I think it just uses the font-size that windows uses...

Comment: I think there should be a way to do it with the Windows API.

Comment: Coulb be, if so, I don't have a clue...
It was just what I was thinking.