# Extend default windows title bar

Tags: c++, .net, windows, winapi, titlebar

Currently, I am looking for a way to extend the title bar of all windows in the system by an additional button, which would run an arbitrary operation. An application doing pretty much what I want is http://www.xtrabuttons.com/. They seem to hook their buttons in all windows, which is exactly what I want to do with my custom operation. The main target system would be a windows 7 computer.

Is there a C# or other API to achieve this?

Comment: This covered [on SO here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841180/how-to-add-an-extra-button-to-the-windows-title-bar)

Comment: Geez, then why did this question here hang around as a tumbleweed for this long? Thanks!

Comment: Wow, I hadn't noticed that before. I just saw the question at the top of the list of unanswered questions ;-)