# How to insert a new button in non client area?

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0, custom-controls, nonclient

im developing a custom form and i need to put a button right next to the minimize button. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P/Invoke would be the way forward there I would say, check out this link on msdn http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/485fb4c5-8430-4cb5-8a4d-ccd7892e403b.

That should get you on your way.

Cheers,
Kevin

Comment: and don't those work or was that not really what you were looking for, if not let me know and I'll see if I can find you a snippet to get you on your way

Comment: i was quite not able to implement them... their source is missing or imcomplete... i would greatly appreciate a recent snipet

Comment: I assume the form will be used on a win7 machine? Let me see if I can wrap something that could get you on your way. I'll get back to you

Comment: For a more recent option, check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841180/how-to-add-an-extra-button-to-the-windows-title-bar. This works and also has an extensive explanation on enabling aero features for it.

Comment: looks very promissing! already voted up... get back to mark as answer as soon as i validate!