# Java - Extra Window Button

Tags: java, jframe, window

Google Chrome Recently had an update that added an extra button onto to the top of the window that allowed you edit your account settings. I have a great use for an extra button like this one but I do not know how to make it. So, how can I add an extra button at the top of the window?

[image: This is what I would like to do.]

This is what I would like to do or have in mind.

Comment: Welcome to the holy grail.  About the only way you'd be able to do this is via JNI/JNA

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841180/how-to-add-an-extra-button-to-the-windows-title-bar) might be of interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an amateur/simple answer but it could be possible just to make a title bar with all of the drop downs without text until you reach the button you want and customize that