# In C# WPF window, adding button for topmost beside standard window buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, button, window, topmost

I'd like add a button for changing window state to topmost to the built-in window buttons such as maximize, minimize, and close [[please refer to this pic.]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zDNb.png)

However, I'm having hard time finding the way out as WPF seems not to provide such an API. I even thought using the icon next to the window title functioning as the button for topmost, but looks not feasible.

Is there anyway like using .dll or could I inherit the window class and add the button and corresponding event handler anyhow?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider replace whole window with yours(completely custom window)?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It will be very difficult as you can see below link:

[How to add an extra button to the window's title bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841180/how-to-add-an-extra-button-to-the-windows-title-bar)

To make things easy, you should consider implementing a custom window for that. This window will have custom buttons including Close,Minimize,Maximize along with any other buttons as well.

Comment: The link only provides answers for window form, not WPF window.. but I appreciate your answer.