# Add Checkbox or Control on Form Border just left to minimize button

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I want to add my checkbox on Windows Form Border, Just Left of Minimized button of Border, As
[image: Button Just Left to Minimize button]

I don't want to create my own Complete border, by Setting `FormBorderStyle = None` and creating complete border with a lot of codes.

How to add control just left to minimize of Border.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841180/how-to-add-an-extra-button-to-the-windows-title-bar

Comment: [Fancy Windows Forms - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33716/Fancy-Windows-Forms) --  [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dwm/customframe).

Comment: Emulating your own border is all you can do. The border is completely controlled by the OS, not by your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second border less window with the control you want with relative positions to the first window. Of course the background of the second window have to be transparent.

If window 1 got moved -> move window 2 ( the transparent border less window with your control) for the same x and y coordinates